# ValidationResult com dois parâmetros

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, validação

Estou tentando utilizar a validação customizada, conforme explicação neste [link](https://www.devmedia.com.br/data-annotations-para-asp-net-mvc-revista-net-magazine-99/25657), porém ai só consigo passar um parâmetro para validar, e eu preciso dos dois, pois se o campo estiver vazio e o outro for false, ele tem que ou preencher o campo Inscrição Estadual ou então marcar como `true` o Inscrição Isento.

Queria algo como:

```
public class Validacao
{
    public static ValidationResult ValidarInscricao(string inscricao, bool isento)
    {
        bool ehValido;

        if (inscricao == null && isento == false)
        {
            ehValido = false;
        }
        else { ehValido = true; }

        if (ehValido)
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return new ValidationResult("A inscrição não é valido.");
    }
}

[Display(Name = "Inscrição Isento")]
public bool InscricaoIsento { get; set; }
[CustomValidation(typeof(Validacao), "ValidarInscricao")]
[Display(Name = "Insc. Estadual")]
public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }
```

Porém não sei como passar os parâmetros para a função.

**Edit**
Também tentei fazer desta forma:
Aqui é o meu HTML:

```
<label asp-for="InscricaoEstadual" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input asp-for="InscricaoEstadual" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
                        <span asp-validation-for="InscricaoEstadual" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <input asp-for="InscricaoIsento" type="checkbox" />
                        <label asp-for="InscricaoIsento" class="control-label"></label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="InscricaoIsento" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
```

Porque a mensagem não está funcionando? Aqui é como coloquei na classe

```
 public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (InscricaoIsento == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(InscricaoEstadual))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("O campo Insc. Estadual é obrigatorio.", new string[] { "InscricaoEstadual" });
        }
    }
```

Não sei se está faltando algo, mas ele não faz a validação.
Ele entra na condição, ele só não aparece a mensagem, ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Eu verifiquei que ele entra na função do controller pra fazer a validação, antes de retorna o erro. Não tem como essa validação ser feita somente no cliente, sem a necessidade de entrar no controller?

Comment: Passe uma classe como parâmetro ao invés de múltiplos parâmetros, é uma solução elegante e você já implementa o SOLID

Comment: @JeanGatto não entendi, tem algum exemplo pra me auxiliar ? o `ValidationResult` aceita passar a classe ?

Comment: Você está usando o **FluentValidation** ou a validação do **DataAnnotations**? Geralmente eu uso o FluentValidation, é muito flexível, https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

Comment: Olhe a documentação aqui, é muito fácil!
https://fluentvalidation.net/start

Comment: @JeanGatto estou utilizando a do `DataAnnotations`

Comment: @JeanGatto estou tentando utilizar o `FluentValidation`, mas como faço a validação de dois campos juntos ?

Comment: já existe uma resposta bem similar a sua pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283166/43340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar essa outra forma de validação (via `CustomValidation`) você cria seu próprio atributo de validação para a propriedade que você escolher.

No seu caso acima, você escolheu a propriedade InscricaoEstadual, informando que a validação ocorrerá via método ValidarInscricao da classe Validacao e adicionando o atributo abaixo nessa propriedade:
`[CustomValidation(typeof(Validacao), "ValidarInscricao")]`.

Para não dar erro, você precisa retirar o segundo parâmetro do método `ValidarInscricao`:

```
    public class Validacao
    {
        public static ValidationResult ValidarInscricao(string inscricao /*, bool isento*/)
        {
            /*
                Aqui você validaria algo específico só da Inscrição Estatual....
            */

            bool ehValido;

            if (inscricao == null /*&& isento == false*/)
            {
                ehValido = false;
            }
            else { ehValido = true; }

            if (ehValido)
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            else
                return new ValidationResult("A inscrição não é valido.");
        }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, como invés de validar uma propriedade, você quer validar duas propriedades ao mesmo tempo, acredito que dessa forma atenda: [Condição if com required ViewModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/331767/condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-if-com-required-viewmodel/331806#331806)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class DataAnnotationsValidatorExtension
{
    public static bool Validate<T>(T instance, out List<ValidationResult> validationResults) where T : class
    {
        validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(instance, null, null);
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(instance, validationContext, validationResults, true);
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
            var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var minhaInstanciaClasse = new MinhaClasse();
        DataAnnotationsValidatorExtension.Validate(minhaInstanciaClasse , out errors);
```

Comment: Desculpe não entendi muito bem, editei a pergunta com a forma que tentei fazer, porém mesmo assim não aparece a mensagem de retorno.